# how expensive are react/react-native components once rendered

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-native, react-native-navigation

this is more of a theoretical question, but i'm playing with the idea of never having my components unmount instead I just do an animation and set the opacity to 0, I was wondering how expensive are components once they are rendered to the DOM and do not need to be re-rendered again?

in theory how many components can one add/ have rendered at once without noticing a difference in performance?

I know its theoretical so i'm very curious on y'alls answers